# Is the part $\mu(r)$ in Bloch wave $\psi(r)=e^{ik\cdot r}\mu(r)$ a real function?

Tags: solid-state-physics

I guess that the part $\mu(r)$ in Bloch wave $\psi(r)=e^{ik\cdot r}\mu(r)$ is a real function. Is it true? If so, how can we prove it? Thank for any help.

Comment: Is this guess based on anything other than a desire for the world to be simple? Can you write down the Schrödinger equation for the Bloch waves and test what happens to it under conjugation?

Answer (score 1):

The argument in 1d runs as follows.  Take $\psi_k(x)=e^{ikx}\mu_k(x)$ and insert this into the Schrodinger equation:
$$
\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} + U(x)\right)\psi_k(x)
= E_k \psi_k(x)
$$
to obtain
$$
\left(\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}-i\frac{\hbar^2 }{m}k\frac{d}{dx}-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}{dx^2} + U(x)\right)\mu_k(x)=E_k\mu_k(x)\, .\tag{1}
$$
Now, assuming the potential $U(x)$ is real, take the complex conjugate of this to get
$$
\left(\frac{\hbar^2k^2}{2m}+i\frac{\hbar^2 }{m}k\frac{d}{dx}-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}{dx^2} + U(x)\right)\mu_k^*(x)=E_k\mu_k^*(x)\, .\tag{2}
$$
which is just the Schrodinger equation for $\mu_{-k}(x)$.  In other words, $\mu^*_k(x)=\mu_{-k}(x)$, and both have the same energy $E_k=E_{-k}$.  Of course is it possible not to work with $\mu_k(x)$ but instead with 
$$
\tilde \mu_k(x)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mu_k(x)+\mu_{-k}(x)\right)=
\frac{1}{2}\left(\mu_k(x)+\mu^*_{k}(x)\right)
$$ 
(which has the same energy $E_k$ as $\mu_k(x)$ and $\mu_{-k}(x)$), which guarantees that $\tilde \mu_k(x)$ real.  The solution 
$$
\frac{i}{2}\left(\mu_k(x)-\mu_{-k}(x)\right)=
\frac{i}{2}\left(\mu_k(x)-\mu^*_{k}(x)\right)
$$
is also real with energy $E_k$.

Roughly speaking, $\mu_k(x)$ is a wavefunction for the problem with an isolated atom, and these (using an appropriate version of the argument above) can always be chosen as real.